# Using recursion to draw patterns in python

Tags: python, recursion

I was looking on this webpage http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/recursion.html and there is a nice recursive solution for drawing a tree, so I decided to write the code myself to draw this "H tree" below.

[image]

What I needed help with was, is there a way to rotate the entire picture by 90 degrees? I tried starting the turtle off in a different angle (left by 90 degrees) and while this works for a depth of 1, it messed up a depth of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just rotate before drawing, *outside* of the recursive function:

```
window = turtle.Screen()
turtle.right(90)
drawHTree(200,2)
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much, I had actually attempted to modify the entire program!

Comment: You're very welcome, especially since I only know about the turtle module thanks to you now :-)